# C# String.SubString With MessageBox Does Not Display Anything

Tags: c#, string, substring, messagebox

I am trying to display part of a `string` using a `MessageBox`, for this I use the `String.SubString` method. However when I run the code the `MessageBox` is not displayed and no error is thrown.

For troubleshooting purposes I display the entire string in a `MessageBox` before trying to display the `substring`.

This displays the following (`Received |<BID>22|`):

[image]

I want to display the number part of the string, however when I try doing this nothing is displayed. Can anyone see what is going wrong please? Here is the code:

```
public void parseMessage(string theMessage)
{
    String message = theMessage.Replace("\n", String.Empty);

    MessageBox.Show("Received |" + message + "|");

    String zoneNumber = message.Substring(5, message.Length);

    if (message.StartsWith("<BID>"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Bid received for zone " + zoneNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the message as text instead of linking to an image-sharing site?

Comment: @DStanley Done, you could've probably edited that in yourself :)

Comment: Though I can't be 100% sure, it appears that it actually starts with ` <BID>` - note the leading space.

Comment: @RudiVisser, easy. He may not have been able to get to that site. It depends on where he is.

Comment: @RudiVisser I would if I had access to imgur.com.

Comment: @DStanley Fair enough! Was just a general comment, not a "dig" at you.

Comment: The answers below are more or less pointing at your problem. But what concerns me more is the fact that you have clearly 'swallowed' the exception thrown by the Substring method call. Otherwise you should already have found your answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't access your linked image, so I don't know for certain what `message` contains, but

```
String zoneNumber = message.Substring(5, message.Length);
```

should throw an exception as it would overflow the length of the string by 5 characters.

Use

```
String zoneNumber = message.Substring(5);
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

How about changing

```
String zoneNumber = message.Substring(5, message.Length);
```

to

```
String zoneNumber = message.Substring(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to display the number part of the string, however when I try doing this nothing is displayed

That's because, looking at your message, **it has leading whitespace** and you are trying to do `StartsWith("<BID>")`

First, `TrimStart`, then try `StartsWith`, or just do `Contains`.

`StartsWith`:

```
if (message.TrimStart().StartsWith("<BID>"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Bid received for zone " + zoneNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

so the problem is that `if (message.StartsWith("<BID>"))` does not return true?

does this help?

```
public void parseMessage(string theMessage)
{
       String message = theMessage.Replace("\r", String.Empty).Replace("\n", String.Empty).Replace("\r\n", String.Empty);
       MessageBox.Show("Received |" + message + "|");
       String zoneNumber = message.Substring(5, message.Length);
       if (message.TrimStart().StartsWith("<BID>"))
       {
          MessageBox.Show("Bid received for zone " + zoneNumber);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use rplace instead of SubString

```
if (message.StartsWith("<BID>"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Bid received for zone " + message.Replace("<BID>",""));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String bidMarker = "<BID>";
int startLoc = message.IndexOf(bid);
if (startLoc != -1)
{
    String zoneNumber = message.Substring(startLoc + bidMarker.Length).Trim();
    MessageBox.Show("Bid received for zone " + zoneNumber);
}
```